# How do I check if InetAddress was created using a hostname or an IP address?

Tags: java, dns, inetaddress

I would like to know that if an InetAddress object was initialized with a hostname or an IP address at construction. Is there a way to check that in java?

Comment: No you can't; but out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The `InetAddress.toString()` returns string representation in following format: `host-name/IP address`. If host name is unknown (that happens when the instance was created using IP address) the first part is empty.

The following code fragment:

```
    System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("localhost").toString());
    System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1").toString());
    System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com").toString());
    System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("173.194.113.145").toString());
```

Prints this output:

```
localhost/127.0.0.1
/127.0.0.1
www.google.com/173.194.113.144
/173.194.113.145
```

So, you can say the following:

```
public static boolean isCreatedFromIp(InetAddress addr) {
    return addr.toString().startsWith("/");
}
```

EDIT: I have not checked this with IPv6, however I believe similar solution exists because `toString()` implementation does not depend on the IP version.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering why all my logged addresses started with a /